# 403 error on Wordpress when publish any page or click on edit button

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

When I click to create or edit a page from the WordPress admin show this error "403 server denied access to this resource!" How can I fix this?

Comment: Be more precise

Comment: Please check and confirm if there's any security plugins in WordPress or any firewall on server side. If so, please try to whitelist your IP address to see if it resolves the issue.